# Resume reading partial input with ZlibStream?

Tags: c#, zlib, dotnetzip

I am having a tough time understanding some behaviours of the `ZlibStream` when receiving partial data from a socket.  On the other end is a C++ server sending zlib'd data and I'm writing the client side.

Here's some behaviour I don't understand:

```
using (var mm = new MemoryStream())
{
  var z = new ZlibStream(mm, Ionic.Zlib.CompressionMode.Decompress);
  var buf = new byte[64];
  int read = z.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);        // 0 of course
  mm.Write(test, 0, test.Length);               // mm contains bytes
  mm.Position = 0;
  read = z.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);            // still 0?!

  z = new ZlibStream(mm, Ionic.Zlib.CompressionMode.Decompress);
  mm.Position = 0;
  read = z.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);            // now read == 13
}
```

It seems once I do an incomplete read from the `ZlibStream` it just gives up and can't be used again.  Which is upsetting as I won't know off-hand if I've received enough data to do a read and hoped that the stream would help me by letting me know that it's done a non-zero read and I could maintain offsets on the stream.

Moreover I found that if I recreate the `ZlibStream` (sounds dumb and maybe expensive) my implementation sort of works except I can never adjust what's in the `MemoryStream` and its length will just get longer and longer.  Truncating (`SetLength(0)`) after a successful read only serves to destroy the compression dictionary (I understand the protocol to be stateful) and I can no longer decode any further messages.

So what am I doing wrong?